# Kernel debug two physical MacBook pro devices

Tags: debugging, kernel, lldb, macos

I've asked the same question at [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67455980/kernel-debug-two-physical-macbook-pro-devices), but i'm gonna copy-paste it here as i might get more relevant answers(?):

I'm trying to kernel debug a physical Macbook pro device.
When my setup contains a VM, between a host MacOS and guest MacOS, its working with no problem using `lldb -o "kdp-remote <guest_machine_ip>"`

my boot-args on my remote (to debug) Macbook are:

```
user$ nvram boot-args
boot-args       debug=0x44 kext-dev-mode=1 pmuflags=1 -v kcsuffix=debug
```

When i'm triggering kernel debug using either
`sudo dtrace -w -n "BEGIN { breakpoint(); }"`
or `LEFT CMD + RIGHT CMD + PowerButton`, the system is in halt mode, not responsive to anything (Mouse not moving, etc)
But when I'm trying to connect to the machine from the host using the lldb command provided earlier, it's not working.
I've made sure the machines can ping each other and I can set up a SSH connection.

To the best of my understanding, I had to user special Apple adapters (`Real™ Ethernet adapter`), so I'm using the following adapters to debug the remote machine:

- https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MMEL2AM/A/thunderbolt-3-usb-c-to-thunderbolt-2-adapter
- https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MD463LL/A/thunderbolt-to-gigabit-ethernet-adapter

The physical connections setup looks like that:

MacOS-Debugger --(USBC to Ethernet adapter)--> Ethernet cable <-- (ThunderBolt to Ethernet adapter) <-- (ThunderBolt3 to ThunderBolt2 adapter) <-- MacOS-debuggee

Generally for the debugging I used the following tutorial, which worked for VM debugging:
https://knight.sc/debugging/2018/08/15/macos-kernel-debugging.html, I didn't find the exact KDK version, but I don't think it should be the problem here

My debugger is `BigSur`, and my debugee is `Catalina`

Any ideas to what the problem may be will be helpful

Answer (score 2):

So there is an answer in the original post, but what i was missing is the interface where i'll be attaching the debugger at in the `boot-args`
so I have to add `kdp_match_name=en24`, where `en24` is the physical interface the machines are communicating at

Just adding here the answer as well, as it might help someone in the future